# Node Fetch on internal docker network

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two docker containers, frontend and backend, using node JS server. I have been trying to fetch data from backend-container to frontend-container, using an internal network address. It doesn't seem to be working. It only works when we use the backend exposed address, which is security breach. Is there any way where I can fetch, using docker local network address. Please help me out.

I tried all the possible and name combinations, that I was able to curl from docker.

Comment: Is the frontend container running a browser application using a framework like React or Angular?  Since that runs in the browser, it's fundamentally outside of Docker (even if the code is served from a container) and can't see any of the Docker-internal names or addressess.

Comment: If you could [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including what URL you're trying to connect to and what error you get, it might help clarify things.

Comment: Also see ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend), if the frontend is actually a browser application.

Comment: have you tried using "host.docker.internal" as hostname and then the correct port for the backend?