# Not able to call another pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kind

I have a backend pod, service related to it "**backend-service**" and another frontend pod trying to access the backend on url **http://backend-service:800**0 . I port forward my frontend , open the url in browser I could see backend url called on networks tab but no request is coming on my backend.

But when port-forward my backend and use url "**http://localhost:8000**", things work

Comment: When you say "frontend pod", do you mean a Pod serving code that runs in the browser?  The browser is outside the cluster and can't see the Kubernetes-internal hostnames; you need to make the backend visible via an Ingress or something similar.  ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) covers a similar case for plain Docker, the Kubernetes Ingress system would replace the reverse proxy discussed there.

Comment: Yes, the frontend pod means that. Ok, I do have ingress in place which I installed using helm and my backend.yaml has ingress host set to local.example.com. And since I am doing this locally I have an entry in my /etc/hosts too. Can you help me where am I going wrong

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

Are you deploying a `Service` for your backend? Without a `Service` you won't be able to access the backend's ports from anywhere unless you port-forward them manually. This is likely why you can't access the backend without a port-forward.

Second: Are your Services in different namespaces? If you are deploying in different namespaces, you can't just use the service name to connect like you can in docker. To connect to a service in Kubernetes, the format is `<serviceName>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. So for you it might be `backend-server.backend.svc.cluster.local`. Check your Services and namespaces and also update your connection strings to use the k8s format.

Answer (score 0):

Since, the frontend was trying to call the backend service through a backend api endpoint, so I had to actually pass the url format like "**local.example.com/backend**". In the url, there should be an ingress path (here **/backend**) pointing to your backend service.

When we try to hit the backend on a browser based setup, its actually the url that needs to be passed not "**serviceName.namespace**"