# Use axios in dev environment inside docker network AND from docker host

Tags: docker, axios, vuejs3, cypress, local

I'm building a web application, that's supposed to run on different docker containers:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    container_name: app-be
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: app-fe
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app

  test:
    build: ./test
    container_name: app-e2e
    command: npx cypress run -b firefox
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://frontend:5173
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./test:/app
```

The frontend is a vuejs app, and I am trying to access the backend via axios; when starting up everything, the app also gets tested by cypress. But I also want to see my changes locally; which is creating my problem:

In order to access the backend from the host, axios would need to use http://localhost:8000 as the address for the backend, but then of course the Cypress tests would fail; for those axios would need to access http://backend:8000 which again is unknown to the host. However I want **both cases covered**.

```javascript
export default {
  data() {
    return { msg: '' };
  },
  methods: {
    getMessage() {
      axios.get('http://backend:8000/') // <-- change to localhost when running in browser
           .then((res) => { this.msg = res.data; })
           .catch((error) => { console.error(error);});
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getMessage();
  },
};
```

Coming from backend development, I would usually solve something like this with different environment files that get sourced according to the environment - but in this case axios runs as JavaScript on the client, so this cannot be solved on the server side, as it is the same server used. One could change this, of course - have two frontend instances running - one for the cypress tests and another for local development, and start them up with different environment variables, but that feels somewhat dirty.

Another workaround is adding the line `127.0.0.1 backend` to the systems `/etc/hosts`, but I don't feel good with this solution either; for me, one main benefit of using docker is to enable others to just download the project and run it without the need of installing anything on their local machine. Needing root rights to change an essential system config somehow defeats that idea.

**So my question:** Is there a better way of solving this problem that I am not seeing? Or are these really the only two options available?

Comment: In ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) I describe a reverse-proxy setup, where you can use a path-only URL and avoid the hostname problem.  Would this potentially work for your development setup as well?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get this to work; I changed cypress to use `CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://proxy`, added the proxy as explained (but changed the port from 8000 to 80), and changed the axios call to `axios.get('/api/')`. This will work in he browser, but Cypress will fail due to an uncaught exception. Apparently, Firefox tries to establish a connection to `ws://localhost/` and fails (can also be seen in browser console). I was unable to figure out why this happens, though - must somehow be connected to nginx, I guess, as this won't occur with direct access..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a better solution that I am happy with, **thanks** to the [comment by **David Maze**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77070467/use-axios-in-dev-environment-inside-docker-network-and-from-docker-host#comment135869465_77070467), but it involved some more work.

After adding the nginx proxy [as explained](https://github.com/dmaze/docker-frontend-hostnames), i.e.

- adding to docker-compose:

```yaml
proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    container_name: app-prx
    ports:
        - 80:80
```

- introducing new Dockerfile in `./proxy/`:

```
FROM nginx:1.25.2-alpine
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

- introducing new config file for nginx in `./proxy/default.conf`:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:5173/;
        }
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000/;
        }
    }
```

and then fixing Cypress to visit `http://proxy/` and fixing the frontend calls to the backend from `http://backend:8000/` to `/api/`, the project would actually show the correct result in the local browser. However, my cypress tests where failing with a strange message:

> An invalid or illegal string was specified

Turns out, that when looking into the console locally you get a more helpful message:

```
    Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost/.
    Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified
        setupWebSocet client.ts: 77
        fallback      client.ts: 42
    (...)
```

I don't know why this is happening, but for some reason when adding an nginx, vite needs to have a websocket specified in the `vite.config.js`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
    ],
    (...)
    server: {
        hmr: {
            port: 5173
            host: "localhost",
            protocol: "ws",
        },
    },
})
```

**NB**: It is important to add all three components - I first left out the port, which led to the same error as before (and therefore took me even longer to figure this out). Depending on how you start your frontend, this might lead to a new error:

```
    Port 5173 is in use, trying another one.
    error when starting dev server:
    Error [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more than once without closing.
```

In this case make sure, that you are explicitly starting the frontend with a port specified. In my case, I am doing this at the end of my `Dockerfile` for my frontend:

```
    CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "5173"]
```

For me, this is a far superior setup compared to the other two I presented above for 4 reasons:

1. It solves my initial problem, i.e. it's runnable both inside docker and from the host, without needing to change the host.
2. It also simplifies all the routes in the frontend (before I created an instance of axios as helper to set the `baseURL: 'http://backend:8000'` and export it to all my components - no need for that anymore).
3. You'd probably want an nginx anyways as soon as you go into production.
4. Given 3, you're not spawning "useless" docker containers that are just copies of other containers with different environment settings just to satisfy client-side Browser scripts.