# API endpoint from a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have two docker containers `frontend` and `api`
The `api` serves Restful API and `frontend` is a Next.JS application

I need a uniform URL which works for both SSR and CSR, when I set `uri` to apollo client, I cannot use `https://api/graphql` because CSR would break and I cannot use `https://localhost:{PORT}/graphql` because SSR would break.

If I would like to conditionally set endpoint it's too cumbersome.

What is the standard and general way (ignore apollo client, I need a solution works for any other usecases) to fix it?

Comment: I had a similar structure for a project I developed using a NextJS frontend and a Symfony API backend. I have an isolated instance of Traefik running in its own network (for pretty local URLs and service routing), and the Docker Compose File runs an NGINX container that will route all `/api` requests through to the Symfony backend, and the rest through to the frontend. If you think it'll help, I can post my config as an answer if you like.

Comment: Thank you, But I am looking for a simpler option

Comment: In ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) I describe an Nginx-based reverse-proxy setup, not unlike @maiorano84's suggestion, and there a simple path `/graphql` should work in both contexts.

Comment: If I run `fetch('/api/hello')` in SSR mode, how host name can be resolved?! It dosen't work

Answer (score 1):

**This won't be a 1-1 fix for your current setup, but hopefully this should give you a step in the right direction**

Per my comment, I have a similar structure that uses a locally running instance of Traefik to route all local traffic through to the underlying service containers using pretty URLs.

My version of Traefik is a little dated, so mileage may vary. But to get it set up the way I have it, run the following two commands (ports 80, 443, and 8080 need to be open):

```
docker network create -d bridge traefik-network
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 8080:8080 \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --name=traefik \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    --network=traefik-network \
    -l traefik.enable=false \
    traefik:2.4 \
    --providers.docker=true \
    --api.insecure=true \
    --entrypoints.web.address=:80 \
    --entrypoints.websecure.address=:443
```

Here are some baseline configurations I'm using for my project. I've left out some of the finer details that will likely be irrelevant to you, so feel free to modify or adjust with your own implementation details:

***docker-compose.yml***

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.23-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80"
    environment:
      FPM_HOST: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_php
      NEXT_HOST: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_node
      NGINX_SERVER_NAME: ${NGINX_SERVER_NAME}
      NGINX_ROOT: ${NGINX_ROOT}
    volumes:
      - ../api:/var/www/html
      - ../logs:/var/log/nginx
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/templates
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_nginx
          - ${NGINX_SERVER_NAME}
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.rule=Host(`${NGINX_SERVER_NAME}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}.entrypoints=web"
    depends_on:
      - backend
      - frontend
  backend:
    image: php:8.1-fpm-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9000"
    volumes:
      - ../api:/var/www/html
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_php
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  frontend:
    image: node:16-alpine
    ports:
      - ${DEV_PORT:-3000}:3000
    volumes:
      - ../frontend:/var/www/html
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_node
    restart: unless-stopped
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"
    command: [ "yarn", "run", "dev" ]
    depends_on:
      - backend
  postgres:
    extends:
      file: ./docker/services-common.yml
      service: postgres
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=false"

volumes:
  postgres:

networks:
  default:
    name: traefik-network
    external: true
```

***nginx/default.conf.template***

```
upstream frontend {
    server ${NEXT_HOST}:3000;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name ${NGINX_SERVER_NAME};
    root ${NGINX_ROOT};
    index index.php;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /api {
        alias ${NGINX_ROOT}/public/;
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass ${FPM_HOST}:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param NGINX_SERVER_NAME http://${NGINX_SERVER_NAME};
    }
}
```

***.env***

```
# Project
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=my-project
PHP_VERSION=8.1

# NGINX
NGINX_PORT=80
NGINX_SERVER_NAME=project.docker.localhost
NGINX_ROOT=/var/www/html

# Node JS
DEV_PORT=3000

# .... Project specific settings
```

In this way, the API can be accessed locally at:

http://project.docker.localhost/api

And the frontend at:

http://project.docker.localhost