# What would the localhost equivalent be for a website running in a container from within the container itself

Tags: docker, syncfusion

I am very new to docker so this is probably a stupid question. But what would the localhost equivalent be for a website hosted in a container from within the container be?

For context we have a basic webpage that we are using a syncfusion component to turn into a pdf. The way this works is that we render the page and then pass in the html and a base url to grab the resources from (css, js etc) and it renders the webpage in chrome and returns a pdf to the end user (https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/convert-html-to-pdf/docker for a basic example).

The issue I am having is getting the base url from within the container. I think that I am getting the wrong end of the stick somewhere and there is a really simple solution I have missed.

I am using visual studio and docker for windows, with the basic linux docker container created using the add docker support feature in visual studio. The exposed ports are 80 and 443.

So far the things I have tried are:

- Adding "DockerfileRunArguments": "--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway" to the launchSettings.json and then passing the base url as "http://host.docker.internal".
- Using the container id which appears to have the default ip of 172.17.0.2
- Using "DockerfileRunArguments": "--network="host" and connecting to "http://localhost"

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use a path-only URL with a reverse proxy, perhaps?  I describe a similar setup in ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend).  The server, the service container, and the client machine running the browser each separately believe they are three separate `localhost`s.