# Docker-Compose - Frontend service cannot use endpoint from backend

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, docker-network

### Context

I am currently working on a multi-container project involving react, django, and (eventually) several datastores all containerized and tied together with docker-compose. This is all developed within vscode devcontainers. The host operating system is Windows 11.

### Problem

I can make requests to my Django API via the browser (and Django's API web interface). However I cannot make requesets to the API via the frontend service. Using the javascript fetch api, I am unable to make requests to any of the following

- `localhost:8000` (NOTE: Many tut's say this should function just fine)
- `0.0.0.0:8000` (NOTE: This will at least throw a NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error, which is still unsolvable)
- `host.docker.internal:8000`
- `192.168.99.100:8000`
- `172.24.0.2:8000`

### What I've Tried

- Proper CORS configuration with Django
- Ensuring all appropriate ports are exposed and forwarded within docker
- Re-implementing the entire project and basing it off of some other halfassed tutorial. TWICE.

### Details

Backend Dockerfile

```
FROM  python:3.10-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . . 
RUN apk add poetry && poetry install
EXPOSE 8000
```

Frontend Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/frontend
    depends_on:
      - backend

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/backend
    command: "poetry run python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Django Settings.py

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["0.0.0.0"] # ADDED CORS

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "corsheaders", # ADDED CORS
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000" # ADDED CORS
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware", # ADDED CORS
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

React App.tsx

```
const App = () => {
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8000`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCurrentTime(data.time);
        setCurrentDate(data.date);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          The date is {currentDate} and the time is {currentTime}.
        </p>{" "}
        <br />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: If the react app is running in your browser (you aren't doing any sort of server-side rendering) then yes `localhost:8000` should work just fine.  You need to describe in **much** more detail what it means that you "cannot make requesets to the API". What specifically is the issue? Do you get timeouts? Network errors? Permissions errors? Please be very specific about the actual error/issue. Also you should try doing something like `curl` or use an app like Postman to test hitting the API if you aren't sure how to debug the React requests in your web browser.

Comment: a host named docker-desktop gets created for 127.0... ip address, mac user here. check hosts file and try using the host name. Also, check network related stuff.. seem you are going for default.

Comment: @MarkB I think issue is he can access rest points from host machine "browser ,curl..etc", but not from another container.

Comment: The react app runs in your web browser, not in the container. The container just serves up the source code files to the web browser where the React app actually runs. Unless of course you have done something to perform server-side rendering of your React app, but there is no indication in your question so far that you have done that. When you run the react app in your web browser, that's where the errors are occurring, correct? You need to become familiar with your browser's developer console and network tabs so you can see what is actually happening.

Comment: @MarkB Drop your assumptions.

- `CURL http://host.docker.internal:8000` returns a 200 with the response I need.

- The browser at `http://host.docker.internal:8000` returns a 200 with the response I need.

- `fetch('http://host.docker.internal:8000').then(response =>/* set state */)`; was having CORS issues that I needed to solve

From there all I needed to do was add `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [http://host.docker.internal:3000]` to Django's settings.py.

Comment: I'd generally point at ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) for this problem, but I'm a little confused about the distinction between "from the browser" and "via the frontend service"; as @MarkB's first comment indicates, the React application is running in the browser and (absent a CORS issue) you should be able to use the same URL as in the browser.

Comment: So it was a CORS error, but you never provided the debug information in the question to show that it was a CORS error. You would have been able to see that was the issue immediately by looking at the request in your browser's developer console network tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's settings.py required the following since the only ports that were accessible were from the `http://host.docker.internal` domain. Not `localhost` as described in many tuts and documentation.

```py
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    ..., 
    "http://host.docker.internal:3000"
]
```