# Dockerized React app unable to access dockerized flask api

Tags: reactjs, docker, flask, docker-compose

I have a dockerized flask api and I can access the endpoints on postman through http://localhost:105 and can see the logs on the container so the api is running correctly. The flask api also has CORS:
`app = Flask(__name__) CORS(app)`
I have a dockerized reactjs app that uses nginx. I can confirm that the app loads correctly running from the container. When the app tries to contact the api at http://goals-api:105, I get an axios network error, err_name_not_resolved. I have both containers on the same network.

Everything works as expected outside of the docker containers

Please see my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - goals-network

  goals-api:
    image: goals-api
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 105:105
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres
    networks:
      - goals-network

  goals-app:
    image: goals-app-nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - goals-api
    networks:
      - goals-network

networks:
  goals-network:
    driver: bridge
```

And my docker file for react app:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY ./src ./src
COPY ./public ./public
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Build step #2: build an nginx container
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY deployment/nginx.default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

My nginx file:

```
server {
    listen       3000;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    }

    location /static {
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
}
```

I have tried having both containers on the same network, having the react app container depend on the api container but none of them worked

Comment: This sounds not unlike the problem in ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend); does the URL/proxy setup described there work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The bridge network host names only work for communication on the Docker network. Communication from goals-api to postgres is between 2 containers on the network, so there you can use the `postgres` hostname.

But your React app runs in a browser outside the docker network. So you can't use the network hostnames there. You have to go through the host.

So, instead of using `http://goals-api:105` in your app, you need to use `http://localhost:105`.

You might get some CORS issues because your app loads from `http://localhost:3000/` but by using `http://localhost:105` you should at least be able to reach the API container.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Hans! I understand now