# Socket.io Kubernetes issues

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am working on a collaborative whiteboard application which is using socket.io to communicate with MongoDB. The backend-service (a separate pod from the whiteboard pod) is responsible for the communication.

e.g. whiteboard app -> backend-service -> mongodb

The issue i am experiencing is an error stating that backend-service cannot be found. I honestly dont know what the issue is since the other pods dont seem to be experiencing issues with connectivity.

The backend-service has no issues with finding the mongo-service and is connected with no issues. However when i use the same technique to connect to backend-service it seems to have issues with finding the domain name.

The error message I receive is:

```
GET http://backend-service:7789/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OnUHS1g net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

It says that the name is not resolved however it does exist.

This is the configuration file for the backend-service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: backend-serv
  labels:
    app: jakubgawel1310-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jakubgawel1310-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jakubgawel1310-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: backend
        image: jakubgawel1310/backend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7789
        env:
        - name: MONGO_URL
          value: "mongodb://mongo-service:27017"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: jakubgawel1310-backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 7789
      targetPort: 7789
```

This is the configuration for the whiteboard:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: frontend-serv
  labels:
    app: jakubgawel1310-frontend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jakubgawel1310-frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jakubgawel1310-frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: whiteboard
        image: jakubgawel1310/frontend
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        env:
        - name: REACT_APP_SERVER_URL
          value: "http://backend-service:7789"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: jakubgawel1310-frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

This has forced my hand, I have no idea where I am going wrong or how to configure Socket.io

This is currently how im connecting to the to socket.io in the jsx file:

```
console.log('MOUNTING BOARD')
        console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL)
        this.socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL);
        console.log("MOUNTED")
        this.setupEventListeners();
        this.setupCanvas();
```

When the app launches it clearly shows that the env config works and is trying to connect to the service name so im not sure what else i need to change/configure for it to work.

Screenshot of the error.
https://cln.sh/GzVPR2TX

We thought that there might be something wrong with the code and the env variables so I went as far as creating a docker compose (worked with no issues) and then used "kompose" to basically convert it to kubernetes. It threw the same error.

Comment: Is that HTTP GET call being made by your backend code, or by code that's running in the end user's browser?  The browser is outside the cluster and can't resolve ClusterIP Service names.  ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) discusses this in a plain-Docker context; in Kubernetes I'd use an Ingress resource in place of the Nginx container I show there.

Comment: @DavidMaze that was exactly the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occurring because the code of the whiteboard application was running on the browser. So they frontend wasnt able to communicate with the backend.

The fix was simply to portforward the backend endpoint.