# The net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error on the web with react

Tags: reactjs, docker, nestjs

I am developing with nestjs and react in a docker environment in a wsl environment. However, when I send communication from web implemented with react to nestjs, I get a net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

However, when I curl http://localhost:8000 in WSL, the communication was possible, and when I curl http://nest:8000을 in react docker container, the communication was possible. And when I sent http://localhost:8000 in react docker container, the same error occurred as in web.

These include setting a proxy in react's package.json, checking your wsl firewall, and changing to app.listen(8000, "0.0.0.0") in nestjs's main.ts.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Does ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) have the details you need?