# Dockerise a client/server setup using socket.io

Tags: docker, docker-compose, socket.io

Forgive the vague question title, I'm a complete beginner and I lack the terminology to pose my question more specifically.

I've been developing a simple application that consists of a game server (using socket.io, so WebSockets) and a game client, which is just an HTTP server. I've finished developing locally and would now like to host it on the servers of my student organisation; seeing as that machine already has Docker installed I figured that would be the easiest solution.

Concretely, in local development I've set the WebSockets server to use port 3141 and the HTTP server to use port 5173. I tried my hand at using `docker compose` and came up with the following configuration:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3141
  frontend:
    build: ./kwispel-client
    ports:
      - 5173
```

Using `docker inspect kwispel-server-server-1` I can then manually figure out the IP address of the HTTP server and connect to it. However, container naming resolution doesn't work; I need that for

- telling the client side of socket.io where to connect to, and passing in http://server:3141 doesn't work;
- telling the server side of socket.io which CORS headers to allow, and passing in http://frontend:5173 doesn't work Locally the project works fine using localhost instead of server or frontend.

If I try defining a shared network, like such:

```yaml
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3141
    networks:
      kwispel-server_gedeeldNetwerk:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.10  
  frontend:
    build: ./kwispel-client
    ports:
      - 5173
    networks:
      kwispel-server_gedeeldNetwerk:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.238.20
networks:
  kwispel-server_gedeeldNetwerk:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.16.238.0/24"
```

so that I can have fixed IP addresses, I can't even connect to the HTTP server on that address.

Am I missing something obvious? Do I need to pass an extra flag to docker-compose up to expose the ports I need? I'm at a complete loss. Any pointers in the right direction are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Docker-internal IP addresses are basically useless.  In particular, in your scenario, they can never be accessed from another machine.  There's no reason to ever look them up, or to directly specify them.

In your Compose [`ports:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports) you've only specified a single port number.  This makes the given container port accessible from the host system and elsewhere, but Docker chooses the port number.  You can find out the port number Docker has chosen using [`docker-compose port`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_port/)

```shellsession
$ docker-compose port frontend 5173
0.0.0.0:32769
$ curl http://localhost:32769
```

That port number will also be usable from a remote system, if you're directly using the Docker engine on a native-Linux host.

It's common to specify *two* port numbers in `ports:`.  That way you choose the host port.

```yaml
services:
  frontend:
    ports:
      - '8080:5173'
```

```bash
curl http://localhost:8080
```

The caveats are that the first port number has to be different from any other container or host process's published port; the second port number has to match the port the process inside the container is running on; and that the process also has to be listening on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address.

It is common, but definitely not required, for the two port numbers to match.

Comment: I will also mention ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) as a potential problem: if the frontend contains something like React code that runs in the browser, it will need to know the dynamic backend port, but this often winds up getting compiled into the code that is served; Docker-container networking won't work for a browser application.  Adding a reverse proxy to this setup can help.

Comment: This helped tremendously, thanks a million!