# Unable to fetch data in React from NodeJS server in the same Docker container

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, deployment, vite

I am encountering an issue with my NodeJS server and React with Vite client applications. Here's a breakdown of my setup:

## Server Side (NodeJS)

I have a NodeJS server with a single endpoint

```js
// CORS enabled
app.use(cors());

app.get("/api/listings/:city/:district/:bedrooms", (req, res) => {
   // Some logic
});
```

Dockerfile exposes port 5454 with `EXPOSE 5454` and in Docker-Compose:

```yaml
server:
  build: ./server
  container_name: server_c
  ports:
    - "5454:5454"
  expose:
    - 5454
```

## Client Side (React with Vite)

I have a component that fetches information from the server:

```jsx
const URL = "https://server:5454";

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoading(true);
  let endpoint = `${URL}/api/listings/${city}/${district}/${bedrooms}`;

  console.log(`Fetching data from ${endpoint}`);

  axios
    .get(endpoint)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("Received data:", res.data);
      setMedianPrice(res.data.medianPrice);
      setAveragePrice(res.data.averagePrice);
      setNumberOfListings(res.data.numberOfListings);
      setIsLoading(false);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("An error occurred while fetching the data:", error);
    });
}, [city, district, bedrooms]);
```

Locally, both running the project and the local container work perfectly. I am also able to get data using `curl` from inside the container. However, upon uploading to the server, I encounter the following error:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

You can access the live version [here](https://binas.kawaiier.dev).
Any assistance in identifying the issue and resolving it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

I attempted several approaches to address the issue

## Changed Client URL

Altered the client-side URL in attempts to resolve the problem:

- https://localhost:5454
  same error
- https://*.*.13.15:5454 (server's external IP. even though it's a bad practice)
  got me `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`
- http://*.*.13.15:5454
  got me `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://binas.kawaiier.dev/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://*.*.13.15:5454/api/listings/tbilisi/all/all'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

SSL is set up correctly though.

## Updated CORS Options on Server

Modified CORS options on the server side using the following configuration:

```js
const options = {
  origin: "*",
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};
app.use(cors(options));
```

Comment: What is the content of your server's `Dockerfile`? Is it only `EXPOSE 5454`?

Comment: No, it's
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5454

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

Comment: Is the `axios.get()` call running in a server before rendered HTML is sent to the client, or as part of a front-end application that runs in the end user's browser?  Also see ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend).

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for providing the link. I attempted the "easy" method as described, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue. It's worth noting that both applications are hosted on the same machine within a single Docker Compose setup. Surprisingly, I'm unable to use either "server:5454" or "localhost:5454" in the browser but able to curl within the docker container

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but it works for me both when the apps are run locally and when the React app lays within my test machine and fetches data from local `https://localhost:5454`. Are you sure your local app runs? Can you test it by entering the `https://server:5454` in the browser? Does calling the simple `fetch` method with the mentioned localhost URL from the console returns any response?

Comment: @DanielStasiak, I'm experiencing a high level of confusion at the moment. When I run the Docker images locally, everything functions seamlessly. I can effortlessly retrieve data from the server via web app and executing curl https://localhost:5454 works as expected from the client container. However, the situation takes a drastic turn when I deploy these identical containers to the server. The console log demonstrates the attempt to reach localhost:5454 on the production site, which can be observed at binas.kawaiier.dev

Comment: I now think that I misunderstood your problem. Why are you trying to reach your localhost from the deployed app? Shouldn't your app point to the deployed backend, e.g. some `https://api.binas.kawaiier.dev`? The `https://localhost` will point to your local machine only, not to the resource on the server.

Comment: @DanielStasiak, I mentioned attempting these changes in the "Changed Client URL" section of the question. I've recently deployed an updated version, and you can observe the errors directly