# Configuring my app to be accessed by another device on the same network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building a docker container that has a frontend (vite+typescript) and backend (flask), separated into two docker images. I can successfully build the container with docker compose and access it without any issues on my computer. When I access it from another device on the same network, the backend doesn't work.

**App Description**

This is a simple application where the date and time are sent from backend to the frontend, where it is displayed. If the date is displayed, then the app was "successful".

**Issue**

When I try to connect to the docker container from my phone on the same network, only the frontend works. I believe this is because in my `fetch` code, I specify `localhost:port` like shown below (the docker container is production, so `8000` is used):

```
export const host =
  import.meta.env.MODE !== 'production'
    ? 'http://localhost:5001'
    : 'http://localhost:8000'

export const get = (
  route: string,
  callback: (response: object) => void,
  errorCallback?: (response: object) => void,
) => {
  fetch(`${host}/${route}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(callback)
    .catch((error) =>
      errorCallback ? errorCallback(error as Error) : console.error(error),
    )
}
```

When I change `host` to use the ip address of my computer instead, I'm able to access the container from my phone successfully (i.e., the date and time are displayed):

```
export const host =
  import.meta.env.MODE !== 'production'
    ? 'http://localhost:5001'
    : 'http://<ipaddress of computer>:8000'
```

I thought that the way I set up the docker compose yaml, it shouldn't matter that it was always localhost, but apparently it does.

**Question:** What is the correct way to set up my `host` variable and/or docker compose yaml so that I don't have to specify the ip address of my computer to access the container from another device on the same network?

**Relevant docker files**

*compose.yaml*

```
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      TZ: America/New_York
    ports:
      - 7023:7023
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - backend
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      TZ: America/New_York
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    networks:
      - frontend

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

*./Dockerfile*

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

ARG NODE_VERSION=18.18.0

################################################################################
# Use node image for base image for all stages.
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine as base

# Set working directory for all build stages.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


################################################################################
# Create a stage for installing production dependecies.
FROM base as deps

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.npm to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage bind mounts to package.json and package-lock.json to avoid having to copy them
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci --omit=dev

################################################################################
# Create a stage for building the application.
FROM deps as build

# Download additional development dependencies before building, as some projects require
# "devDependencies" to be installed to build. If you don't need this, remove this step.
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=package.json,target=package.json \
    --mount=type=bind,source=package-lock.json,target=package-lock.json \
    --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.npm \
    npm ci

# Copy the rest of the source files into the image.
COPY . .
# Run the build script.
RUN npm run build

################################################################################
# Create a new stage to run the application with minimal runtime dependencies
# where the necessary files are copied from the build stage.
FROM base as final

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Run the application as a non-root user.
USER node

# Copy package.json so that package manager commands can be used.
COPY package.json .

# Copy the production dependencies from the deps stage and also
# the built application from the build stage into the image.
COPY --from=deps /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 7023

# Run the application.
CMD npx http-server ./dist -p 7023
```

*./backend/Dockerfile*

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.11.4
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Use production environment by default.
ENV FLASK_ENV production

WORKDIR /app

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD gunicorn 'app:app' --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: In ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) I describe a reverse-proxy-based setup that doesn't require knowing the deployed host's name at all.  Will that approach work for you here?

Comment: "What is the correct way to set up my host variable and/or docker compose yaml so that I don't have to specify the ip address of my computer to access the container from another device on the same network?" You'll still need to know the IP address on the client end, but the server end can bind to `0.0.0.0` to bind to all addresses.  In the docker context, that means you can reach it through forwarded ports.

Comment: @DavidMaze That looks like it's exactly what I need to fix my issue. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: @DavidMaze I cloned your repo and tried to access the app from my phone. All of those get requests failed, but the "GET localhost" request works from my computer. It looks like I'll have to do something similar to what you did, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: @DavidMaze The link you provided wasn't *exactly* what I needed, but it did point me in the right direction and I now have what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My backend wasn't working when accessing from another device on the network because I needed to use nginx as a reverse proxy. In my nginx.conf file, was able to specify the name of the docker service and docker port being used.

*nginx.conf*

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;

error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid       /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

  sendfile        on;
  #tcp_nopush     on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  #gzip  on;

  #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


  upstream loadbalancer {
    server backend:7001; #### docker service name and port ####
  }

  server {
    listen 7000; #### docker port ####
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      try_files $uri /index.html /index.htm =404;    
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass http://loadbalancer;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }

}
```

Then, I was able to set my `host` variable like this:

```
export const host = import.meta.env.MODE !== 'production' ? 'http://localhost:5001/api' : '/api'
```