# Using a separate Nginx Docker container as a Gateway between the frontend and backend for development

Tags: docker, nginx, frontend, backend, gateway

I'm learning to create complex projects that have a frontend and a backend. Currently no production. For this I try to use Docker containers. Python project using aiohttp. My idea is to make separate containers for the frontend and backend and view the result in the browser at different addresses. That is, go to at least localhost:8080 (there is an HTML dummy page for the front) and localhost:8081 (json is output). At the moment, I did this using separate nginx settings. But there is an idea that I can raise an additional container with nginx as a getway. And with the further development of the project, I would like to transfer this principle to production including redirecting to port 443. But I can't do it. Although I can still log in via localhost.
I can’t understand, my idea is fundamentally wrong and this cannot be organized (and perhaps this should not be done, because it is superfluous), or I have an error somewhere.
Here's what I managed to do (I publish the contents of the files in the order they are presented in the project diagram):

**Project structure**

> 

```
project-root/
│
├── api/
│   ├── docker/
│   │   ├── development/
│   │   │   ├── nginx/
│   │   │   │   ├── conf.d/
│   │   │   │   │   └── default.conf    # Backend configuration
│   │   │   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── public/
│   │   ├── main.py
│   │   └── favicon.ico
│   ├── media/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── storage/
│
├── frontend/
│   ├── docker/
│   │   ├── development/
│   │   │   ├── nginx/
│   │   │   │   ├── conf.d/
│   │   │   │   │   └── default.conf    # Frontend configuration
│   │   │   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── public/
│   │   ├── css/
│   │   ├── js/
│   │   ├── img/
│   │   ├── app.css
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── index.html  # HTML dummy page
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── requirements.txt
│
├── gateway/
│   ├── docker/
│   │   ├── development/
│   │   │   ├── nginx/
│   │   │   │   ├── conf.d/
│   │   │   │   │   ├── api.conf         Backend configuration
│   │   │   │   │   └── frontend.conf    # Frontend configuration
│   │   │   │   └── Dockerfile
│
├── .env
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Makefile
└── README.md
```

**default.conf for api:**

> 

```
server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.html;
    root /app/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api-aio:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias ./api/public/;
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile for nginx in api:**

> 

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine

COPY ./conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /app
```

**main.py**

> 

```
from aiohttp import web
import json

app = web.Application()

# Setting up static files
app.router.add_static('/static/', path='./public', name='static')

# We pass json
async def handler(request):
    context = {'name': 'World'}
    return web.json_response(context)

    return response

app.router.add_get('/', handler)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, port=8081)
```

**Dockerfile for api**

```
# Use the Python base image from Alpine
FROM python:3.10-alpine

# Install dependencies
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy all files from the current directory to /app in the image
COPY . /app/

# Launch the application when the container starts
CMD ["python", "public/main.py"]
```

**default.conf for frontend:**

> 

```
server {
    listen 80;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.html;
    root /app/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}
```

**Dockerfile for frontend:**

> 

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine

COPY ./conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /app
```

**api.conf for gateway:**

> 

```
server {
    listen 8081;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://api-aio:8081;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**frontend.conf for gateway:**

> 

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://frontend:80;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile for gateway:**

> 

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine

COPY ./conf.d /etc/nginx/conf.d

WORKDIR /app
```

**docker-compose.yml**

> 

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  gateway:
    container_name: cont_gateway
    build:
      context: gateway/docker/development/nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8081:8081"
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - api

  frontend:
    container_name: cont_audio_front
    build:
      context: frontend/docker/development/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app

  api:
    container_name: cont_api-nginx
    build:
      context: api/docker/development/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
    depends_on:
      - api-aio

  api-aio:
    container_name: cont_api-aio
    build:
      context: api/
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app
```

With this, I can go in with exec and ping all containers by name from any container on the docker network. I looked at the addresses using "docker inspect". But from my PC I can only ping the address and only the backend. Front and getway do not ping. In the browser, I also cannot access either http://api, or http://api-aio, or http://frontend. I tried to assign ports to them, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: It seems like you've reproduced your entire application in the question; can you [edit] the question to reduce it to a [mcve], keeping only the code that's needed to demonstrate the problem?  Can you make it clearer what the specific problem is?  In ["Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060233/unknown-host-error-calling-containerized-backend-from-frontend) I describe the sort of reverse-proxy setup you describe, and explain why the browser can't see `http://api`; does that setup help you?

Comment: (If you are new to this technology stack, I might consider putting Docker aside for the moment and building this application using plain Node and Python.  Docker does add some significant compleity, especially if you're trying to inject it into your day-to-day development workflow.)

Comment: Also not an answer to the actual question, but just wanted to point out that what you are trying to build could be achieved much more easily with a tool like traefik (https://traefik.io/traefik/), so unless you are looking to do some heavy customization on the gateway, a reverse proxy like traefik would suit your usecase well.

Comment: @David Maze You're right. This is all the code for my initial project. I published almost all of it because I don’t know where I could be wrong. Before adding the Getaway container, I made a mistake in a completely unexpected place, in the Python file itself, by specifying the wrong path to the executable file. Therefore, since the project has just begun, I decided to publish almost the entire thing. And yes, I want to do something similar to what you describe in the link, but I still don't understand what the problem might be.

Comment: @David Maze No, I can do a simple application. I'm interested in the task of learning how to work with Docker and making complex projects divided into containers into front-end and back-end. Moreover, as I said in my question, with localhost I can go to the page in the browser and see exactly what I expect to see.

Comment: @Teemu Risikko Oh yes, I heard about traefik. But I'm just at the beginning of my journey and would like to try both technologies. So this will be my next step after I learn how to make a project using Nginx

Comment: @David Maze I removed some of the code from the question as best I could. But this didn't help much. I suspect that I have something mixed up in the paths of one of these files. And, unfortunately, your example from Github has not helped me yet.